# How to display search results in one table with PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code to do the search. But the search results are not in the same table. All search results appear in a different table. How do I make them appear in one table?

> **Screenshot :**

[image: Screenshot of my application]

And here's my code :

```
> search.php

<?php

    $query = $_GET['query'];


    $min_length = 1;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barang WHERE (`tanggal` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
                ?>

                <table width="107%" class="view">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <th width="180">Tanggal</th>
        <th width="150">Barang Masuk</th>
        <th width="90">Bijih Keluar</th>
        <th width="120">Kantong Hitam Keluar</th>
        <th width="120">Kantong Putih Keluar</th>
        <th width="90">Stok Bijih</th>
        <th width="90">Stok Kantong Hitam</th>
        <th width="90">Stok Kantong Putih</th>
        <th width="130">Catatan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>



                    <td><?php echo $results['tanggal']; ?></td>



                <td><?php echo $results['barang_in']; ?></td>


                        <td><?php echo $results['bijih_out']; ?></td>


                <td><?php echo $results['htm_out']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $results['pth_out']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $results['bijih']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $results['kantong_htm']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $results['kantong_pth']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $results['note']; ?></td>
   <?php             
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "Hasil tidak bisa ditemukan atau tidak ada di dalam database.";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

So how to make the search results appear just in one table? Am I wrong to put the table code? Or something else? And one more question, How to add numbers for each result? Thank you in advance for your time and the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<table>` tag outside your while loop and also add a `<TR>` tag inside the while loop and dont forget to close  tag. 
For Serial Number you have to introduce another variable as a counter. In the code given below i added `$i`. Change it if you had already used $i in your code. 
I think after changing your code will look like

```
?>
    <table width="107%" class="view">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SN</th>//new Line
          <th width="180">Tanggal</th>
          <th width="150">Barang Masuk</th>
          <th width="90">Bijih Keluar</th>
          <th width="120">Kantong Hitam Keluar</th>
          <th width="120">Kantong Putih Keluar</th>
          <th width="90">Stok Bijih</th>
          <th width="90">Stok Kantong Hitam</th>
          <th width="90">Stok Kantong Putih</th>
          <th width="130">Catatan</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
<?php
    $i=1;//new line
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i; ?> </td>//new line
      <td><?php echo $results['tanggal']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['barang_in']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['bijih_out']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['htm_out']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['pth_out']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['bijih']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['kantong_htm']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['kantong_pth']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['note']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php             
    $i++;//new line
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
  echo "Hasil tidak bisa ditemukan atau tidak ada di dalam database.";
}
```

Comment: hey, it works! Thank you, can I have one more question? How to add numbers for each results? hehe

Comment: check the answer :) Always Welcome

Comment: happy to help.. and always use proper indentations

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<table>` tag outside of your `while` loop.

Should be like this..

```
  echo "<table width="107%" class=/"view/">";
  while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
                ?>

  <!-- Comment this 
                <table width="107%" class="view">

  -->
  <thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    $min_length = 1;
    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
    { 
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barang WHERE (`tanggal` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
        { 
?>
        <table width="107%" class="view">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="180">Tanggal</th>
                <th width="150">Barang Masuk</th>
                <th width="90">Bijih Keluar</th>
                <th width="120">Kantong Hitam Keluar</th>
                <th width="120">Kantong Putih Keluar</th>
                <th width="90">Stok Bijih</th>
                <th width="90">Stok Kantong Hitam</th>
                <th width="90">Stok Kantong Putih</th>
                <th width="130">Catatan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<?php
        while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results))
        {
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results['tanggal']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['barang_in']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['bijih_out']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['htm_out']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['pth_out']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['bijih']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['kantong_htm']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['kantong_pth']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['note']; ?></td>
            </tr>
   <?php             
        }
?>
        </table>
<?php

        }
        else
        { // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "Hasil tidak bisa ditemukan atau tidak ada di dalam database.";
        }

    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```